# Table of Signs and variation

Tags: tkz-tab

I do not understand how to put an arrow on several columns. I would like to put an arrow that goes down between 0 and 25

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , B'(x) / 1, B(x) / 1}{$0$, $5.7$, $25$, $63.3$, $70$}
\tkzTabLine{,-, ,-,z,+, ,-,}
\tkzTabVar{+/,-/} %, ,+/, -/}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `\tkzTabInit` line, you may only enter the boundaries of the domains where your function is monotonic. Then, you will have to add a `\tkzTabVal` line at the end, where you can put all your intermediate values. I let a short example below, since what you want is not completely clear to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$x$/1,$f(x)$/2}{$-5$, $0$, $1$, $8$}
        \tkzTabVar{+/$2$,-/$0$,+/$4$,-/$-5$,}
        \tkzTabVal{3}{4}{0.4}{$3$}{$0$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tkz-tab with intermediate val]

Here the `\tkzTabVal{3}{4}{0.4}{$3$}{$0$}` instruction stands for "insert at `pos=0.4` (i.e. 40% distance) between the 3rd and the 4th value of the vartab both values `$3$` in the first line and `$0$` in the second line".

You would take a great benefit in reading the documentation, which is extraordinary well done, with a lot of examples.

#### EDIT

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for but here's something to start with, using your initial table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , B'(x) / 1, B(x) / 2}{$0$, $25$, $63.3$, $70$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,z,+,z,-,}
        \tkzTabVar{+/$2$,-/$-1$ ,+/, -/}
        \tkzTabVal{1}{2}{0.5}{$5.7$}{$0$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabvar2]

#### ANOTHER SOLUTION

could be to use `R/` argument to pass above values declared in the first line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , B'(x) / 1, B(x) / 2}{$0$,$5.7$, $25$, $63.3$, $70$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,,-,z,+,z,-,}
        \tkzTabVar{+/$2$,R/,-/$-1$ ,+/, -/}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: v3]

Comment: thank for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Hope you got what you were looking for.